# No topicDistributions(..) method in ml.clustering.LocalLDAModel

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-2.0

I am using `org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.LDA` for topic modelling (with online optimizer)
and it returns `org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.LocalLDAModel`. However, using this model there
doesn't seem to be any way to get the topic distribution over documents.
While older `mllib` API (`org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LocalLDAModel` ) does have the method
for exactly that i.e. `org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LocalLDAModel.topicDistributions(..)`

I am not sure why it is so. Specially, given that the new `ml.LDA` uses older
`mllib.LDA` and wraps the older `mllib.LocalLDAModel` itself in the new
`ml.LocalLDAModel`.

So, can someone please clarify:
1. Why this is so?
2. What is the correct way, if any, to get topic distributions in the new
`ml.LocalLDAModel`?

P.S. I can always modify the spark code to expose the old API but I am not sure why was it hidden in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `ldaModel.transform(dataset)` which extends your dataset with an additional column `topicDistribution` where you get what you want (`dataset` is the dataset that you passed to the `fit()` method of your `LDAModel` instance.